# Can't enter UEFI Boot Manager on Dell R610

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, dell-poweredge

This system seems to have a hybrid BIOS / UEFI setup.

Before doing anything, I reset the NVRAM of the machine using the Clear NVRAM jumper on the motherboard..

I can get into the BIOS, and I have set a BIOS password.

When I try to enter the UEFI boot manager, it asks for my 'Setup Password'.

But the password I set for the BIOS doesn't work, and neither does a blank password.  Any ideas?

Comment: There can often be two passwords in relation to a BIOS, almost like a user and an administrator. I suggest you remove all passwords from the BIOS and then try to access the boot menu, let me know how you get on.

Comment: This particular machine only has a Setup Password (for config) and a System Password (for boot)

Comment: Can you not remove all passwords via the BIOS?

Comment: If you enter the wrong password 3 times does it display a random number? if so, check this blog out >> http://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html << Otherwise manufactures sometimes include backdoor passwords, search for that.

Comment: Entering the wrong password 3 times simply halts the system and requires a reboot.

Comment: Figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

First, I thought maybe my use of symbols (non-alphanumeric characters) was screwing up the password somehow.  I removed these from the BIOS password but I still wasn't getting into the UEFI successfully.

Decided to re-read the user manual again (which does not mention UEFI setup password specifically, only "Setup Password"), but more carefully this time.

Ran across this line:

> You can use up to 32 characters in your password.
>   As you type, placeholders appear in the field.
>   *The password assignment is not case-sensitive.* To erase a character, press `Backspace` or the left-arrow key.

[Italics Mine]

Well this got me thinking.  I configured a multi-case password like `aBcD1234` in the BIOS, and I was attempting to enter the *exact* password to enter the UEFI, but it was being rejected.

Here's what was happening: because the BIOS was case-*in*sensitive, it was recording my original password of `aBcD1234` as the all-lowercase `abcd1234` and passing that on to the access control of the UEFI boot manager.  Apparently the UEFI boot manager password prompt is case-*sensitive* and so it was not accepting my entry of `aBcD1234`.  When I tried `abcd1234`, I was able to enter the UEFI boot manager.

Comment: Be sure to report that problem to the manufacturer, since it's a serious firmware bug!

Comment: Considering the R610 is at least 5-years old, I doubt they would care.

Comment: Bugs like that can lurk undetected for years, so it's still worth reporting.

Comment: I had this same issue with my R710